# Does unetbootin work in win 10 with UEFI mode?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, unetbootin, ubuntu-15.10

I would like to install Ubuntu 15.10 using unetbootin and no usb key -thus using unetbootin with Hard Disk (frugal) install mode.

However nowhere in the documentation could I see if unetbootin will work in `type>disk`in windows 10.

It only states [how it works in windows 200/xp or Vista/7](http://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/howitworks/#hard-disk-frugal-install-mode):

I fear I might not even be able to boot windows again.

Comment: Take a look at the official Ubuntu documentation: [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) before you commit to creating the bootable USB. It's up-to-date and works on Windows 10 with UEFI mode. My personal experience with UNetbootin is that UNetbootin **does not work** in cases where it does not specifically say in the UNetbootin documentation that it is supported.

Comment: That I did - the problem is I don't have a USB stick at hand. I would like to use the hard disk install mode instead..

Comment: A USB stick costs about $5 USD or maybe you can borrow a USB stick for a few hours to make a bootable Ubuntu live USB and then delete the files that you wrote to the USB stick when you are finished using them.